# Kafka Log4j.xml appender

Tags: log4j, apache-kafka

i have installed kafka and is working fine now i am trying to add log appender to my existing application's log4j.xml file so that i can push messages into Kafka, so any examples of log4j.xml kafka appender would be really helpful, i have added below dependency to my pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

here is what i added into my log4j.xml

```
<appender name="kafka" class="kafka.producer.KafkaLog4jAppender">   
        <param name="topic" value="test" />
        <param name="brokerList" value="localhost:9092" />
        <param name="compressionType" value="none" />
        <param name="requiredNumAcks" value="0" />
        <param name="syncSend" value="true" />  

        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}] %p: %c{1}.%M() - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

And here is the error after adding this

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.getTimeStamp()J     at
>   kafka.producer.KafkaLog4jAppender.append(KafkaLog4jAppender.scala:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:65)
>     at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:203)   at
>   org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:388)    at
>   org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:853)  at
>   org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.log(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:597)    at
>   org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.info(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:159)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:272)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:656)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1635)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0):

Here are my results. I tested it with kafka 0.8.2.2. Please make sure to add the following dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is the sample log4j file:

```
 log4j.rootLogger=INFO
 log4j.appender.KAFKA=kafka.producer.KafkaLog4jAppender
 log4j.appender.KAFKA.BrokerList=sandbox.hortonworks.com:6667
 log4j.appender.KAFKA.Topic=test2
 log4j.appender.KAFKA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout    
 log4j.appender.KAFKA.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n
 log4j.appender.KAFKA.syncsend=true
 log4j.logger.org.nk.kafkatut.producer=INFO, KAFKA
```

Here is my sample application code which is using log4j:-

```
package org.nk.kafkatut.producer;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
public class Log4jAppenderDemo {
public static final Logger LOG =   LoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jAppenderDemo.class.getName());
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LOG.info("test message:1");
    LOG.info("test message:2");
}
```

}

Comment: i have updated with log4j.xml entries and the error i see after that

Comment: @GG0424 It looks like log4j dependency issue. Can you please post entire content of your log4j.xml.